# I have variable Item name ,how to pass this variable to Url?

Tags: django

I have variable Item name  ,how to pass this variable to Url ?

**html**

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<form action="" method="POST" >
 {% csrf_token %}
{{ field.errors }}
<p style="font-size:30px" id="t">Chose The Item</p>
{{ form.Item }}
<a href="{% url 'ItemState' name=form.Item %}">
```

Done

**Form**

```
 iclass ItemState1(forms.Form):
Item = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Product.objects.filter(state=1))
```

**Url**

```
  path('ItemState/<name>', ItemState, name='ItemState'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace name=form.Item with name=form.Item.value in html template

form.Item will return form field and form.Item.value will return selected form value.